# Essential extensions of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> If $A$ and $B$ are right modules over a ring $R$ with $A \subset B$.
> Then $B$ is an essential extension of $A$ if every nonzero submodule
> $C$ of $B$, $C \cap A$ is nontrivial.
>
> (a) Show $\mathbb{Q}$ is an essential extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ as
> $\mathbb{Z}-$mod
>
> (b) Show $\mathbb{R}$ is not an essential extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ as
> $\mathbb{Z}-$mod.
>
> (c) If $ N$ is a submodule of an R-module $M$, show $M$ has a
> submodule $E$ that is maximal with respect to the property that $E
>  \cap N = \{0\}$

So I am not sure what being right-module here matters, but here are my ideas so far

(a) I think I have to argue by contradiction? So suppose $C \subset Q$ and $C \cap Z = \{0\}$, so $C$ only has elements of the form $p/q$ where $q$ does not divide $p$? But this is where I am stuck

(b) I am using the same strategy, assume it is an essential extension. So let $J \subset R$ and $J \cap Q \neq \{0\}$ so there is an element $x \in J \cap Q$. here where I am getting stuck, I think the key is to say that $x$ might be irrational but irrationals don't form a group, so I have no further leads.

(c) I don't understand what this question is asking. Do I ahve to consider the set of all submodules $\{ E: E \cap N = \{0\} \}$ and show it has a maximal element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a) There is no need to argue by contradiction. You can just prove it directly. Let $A$ be a nonzero submodule of $\mathbb Q$.  Pick an arbitrary nonzero element $\frac ab\in A$. Are you sure you can't think of a nonzero multiple of this that is in $\mathbb Z$?  Once you see why this is possible, you've shown $A\cap \mathbb Z$ is nonzero.

b) You would not really want to "argue by contradiction" because you are not proving an if-then, you are seeking a counterexample. Just pick two submodules of $\mathbb R$ which you are pretty sure whose $\mathbb Z$ multiples don't overlap with $\mathbb Q$.  For example, try $\mathbb Q$ and $\sqrt{2}\mathbb Q$

c) **Yes** the strategy you describe is the right way to go. You will find that Zorn's Lemma applies to the set of submodules that you described. In fact, if $B$ is a maximal element of that set, $N\oplus B$ is an essential submodule of $M$.

Comment: (a) I am guessing if $a/b \in A$, then closure says $b(a/b) \in A$ and the element $b(a/b) = a\in Z$?

(b) I guess your example works. $\sqrt(2)Q$ can be regarded as a Z-module that has an element $(\sqrt(2))$ not contained in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: (c) So I am just going to mimic every Zron lemma application here seeing it probably works here as well. Start with a chain $(E_{\alpha}) \subset J = \{E: N \cap E = 0 \}$, then consider $\cup_{\alpha} E_{\alpha}$. We have to show it is in $J.$ to that end, since $N \cap E_{\alpha} = 0$ for every $\alpha$, $\cup (E_{\alpha} \cap N) = 0.$ Now my last worry is, can I distribute $(\cup_\alpha E_{\alpha}) \cup N = (\cup_\alpha( E_{\alpha} \cup N) $ since we are working with arbitrary union?

Comment: @Hawk The last sentence of the first comment isn't quite reasoned right. If you had $q_1 = \sqrt{2}q_2$, for two rational numbers $q_1$ and $q_2$, you'd have to find a contradiction.  $\mathbb Q$ could contain a *different* multiple of $\sqrt{2}$ other than just $\sqrt{2}$, in principle.

Comment: sorry, if $x \in \sqrt(2)\mathbb{Q} \cap \mathbb{Q}$ then $x = q_1$ and $x = q_2\sqrt{2}$, so $q_1 = \sqrt{2}q_2 \implies q_1/q_2 = \sqrt{2}$, that is the contradiction.

Comment: @Hawk For your second comment: ok you've started with the right assumptions but gotten a little distracted. What you want to show is that $((\cup E_\alpha)\cap N=\{0\}$. Suppose it was not, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Okay i see where you are going, if there is a nonzero $x \in N \cap \cup E_\alpha$, then the intersection shows $x \in N$ and $x \in  E_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$, but that is $x \in N \cap E_{\alpha} = 0$, a contradiction. I was trying to shortcut it, but I am guessing my worry before is answered, you can't distribute arbitrary set operation like that.

Comment: @Hawk well I think they do distribute, but the answer isn't nearly as clear writing it that way, IMO

Comment: I might as well tell you what I was trying to do. I was trying to write $( \cup E_k) \cap N = \cup (E_k \cap N) = \cup 0.$ The last equality is $0$,since $E_k \in J$ for each $k$.

Comment: I don't know if you will see this, but what exactly did being right module in this question has to do with anything?

Comment: @Hawk It doesn't have anything to do with anything here. It's equally true for left modules.